# UIViewController option data from segue or NSUserdefault

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have the problem with pass data between controller. In requirement, I have used tab bar, there is root to "search people view" and "profile view". when I click profile view, the data is from my `NSUserDefaults` data but if I click the people cell from search people view, the profile view should display the data from people cell. I'm confused how to handle that case. Are there possible to identification the segue identifier that in to profile view.
please help, prefer swift code

UPDATE:

this is my code on "search people view":

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowAlumniAngkatan" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailProfile{
            let indexPath = ListAlumniTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let data = SearchResult[indexPath!.row]
        }
    }
}
```

and below is "Profile view" code :

```
class ProfileDetailsViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var BackgroundImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ProfileTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var ProfilePictureImage: UIImageView!

var Profiles:DetailProfile!
var contacts:[Contact] = [Contact]()
var work:[Work] = [Work]()
var advise:String!

var SeeMoreEnbable:Bool!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    InitializationView()
    SeeMoreEnbable = false
    getData()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// MARK - Init View
func InitializationView(){
    blurImage()
    circleImage()
}

func getData(){
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserDetail") as! [NSData]
    self.advise = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(defaults[3] as NSData) as! String
    let temp1 =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(defaults[2] as NSData) as! [NSArray]
    for data in temp1{
        let jabatan = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data[0] as! NSData) as! String
        let perusahaan = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data[1] as! NSData) as! String
        let tahunkerja = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data[2] as! NSData) as! String
        self.work.append(Work(Jabatan: jabatan, Perusahaan: perusahaan, TahunKerja: tahunkerja))
        print(work[0].Jabatan)
        print(work.count)

    }
    let temp2 =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(defaults[1] as NSData) as! [NSArray]
    for data in temp2{
        let Type = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data[0] as! NSData) as! String
        let Detail = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data[1] as! NSData) as! String
        self.contacts.append(Contact(ContactType: Type, ContactDetail: Detail))
    }
}
```

}

I have implemented `prepareForSegue` on search people view that should send the data from row that selected. But I don't have idea about choose data from segue or from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Please paste the code for readers better understanding

Comment: U just need to create an instance of the profileVC and pass the data as a property to it before present it with segue

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the segue an `identifier` in your storyboard. Then in your "search people view" controller implement `prepareForSegue` method. By using this method you can set data to the next viewcontroller (profile view), by storing them in some of profile view's field variables.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

  if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ProfileViewController {
    vc.profileData = selectedProfileData
  }
}
```

Comment: i have implemented your code, but that not work to choose the data that must display in profile view

Comment: Oh wait, i misunderstood your question. The problem is you have some weird UX going on. Why would you select the profile on the tab bar to show the profile of a person you've searched and possibly clicked in a tableview? That makes no sense. Try to instead keep the profile tabbutton only to your own profile, and instead you can reuse the layout and code when you click a searched person, to show details (push details segue).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tab bar controller then you can use below method to pass data b/w view controllers

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
     if(viewController.isKindOfClass(AddReminderViewController)){
            let vc = viewController as! AddReminderViewController
            vc.name = "Demo"
     }
     return false   
}
```

Comment: where i must add that code? in UITabBarController hasn't that function